# Where to store SQLite file from app user

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

In my project I have stored my sqlite(DB file) file in Document directory and also set UIFilesharingMode - NO , but now user can able to acces the file using Xcode->orginizor and also he can able to modify in table and able to change the data in that dable .

My requirement is, how I can hide or restrict user to not access that file.
If any one have any intelligent idea please share me.

Thanks.

Comment: out of curiosity.Why? Why you want to do it? ultimately it runs in device and there is no xcode in it

Comment: User wont be able to take your app to xcode until you provide the source code. He wont be able to view/modify the table.

Comment: here no need source code , if you have xcode IDE simply you connect your device and open xcode go window->organizor then select your device and select your app ,then you can download the app data and modify it. That I want to restrict.

Comment: Not every user can use Xcode Organizer to download your app's data. You are able to do this only when your device is used for development and you have installed that app during development (or by enterprise IPA). You can't access to data of app you have installed from AppStore even if your device is used for development. So if you are planning to distribute you app using AppStore, user can not edit SQL database in no way (well, in fact, its possible on jailbroken device, but that is a different story :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use encryption. There's no way to prevent someone accessing Documents folder and there's nowhere for you to store the sqlite file.

Comment: Thanks, is there any free API to encrypt the sqlite file. please forword link

Comment: http://sqlcipher.net/ This may be more than you need. I suggest you to only encrypt the values that you want to keep secret. You can search for it on google, it's simple.